# nhibernate, stored procs

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, hbmxml

Can we call a STOREDPROC which inserts data into db which has no return value from NHIBERNATE? If so can any one please help me out with a small sample.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works if you define the query in XML, but you can simply create an `ISQLQuery` and call `ExecuteUpdate()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ADO.NET, 
-Get Connection object from NHibernate session,
-Create a Dbcommand
-Set your procedure in Dbcommand text
-Run the command

Note: NHibernate might supprot stored procs but its a complicated process refer to this [link](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx), so opt ADO.NET which is optimum in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:-

In your mappings file:-

```
<sql-query name="UpdateMeetingsSentFromTeamLeader">
  <![CDATA[exec uspUpdateMeetingsSentFromTeamLeader :MeetingId]]>
</sql-query>
```

and your code is:-

```
public void UpdateMeetingsSentFromTeamLeader(int meetingId)
{
    Session
    .GetNamedQuery("UpdateMeetingsSentFromTeamLeader")
    .SetInt32("MeetingId", meetingId)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
}
```